# Recusrive function to calculate scores

Tags: php, recursion

I have an array as follows:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'result' => null, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => [
            ['result' => 5, 'weight' => 50, 'children' => []],
            ['result' => 5, 'weight' => 50, 'children' => []]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'result' => 3, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => []
    ],
];
```

What I would like to achieve is run a function, like:

```php
function calculateScores(&$array)
{

}

calculateScores($array);
```

with the desired result:

```php
$array = [
    [
        'result' => 5, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => [
            ['result' => 5, 'weight' => 50, 'children' => []],
            ['result' => 5, 'weight' => 50, 'children' => []]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'result' => 3, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => []
    ],
];
```

So basically, the entry with children gets his scores calculated by multiplying the children's results and weights. In the given example, that would be: 50% *5 + 50% + 5.

So, basically. If an entry has children, its score must be calculated by multiplying the results with the respective weights of these.

As the $array could have more than one level, a recursive function could do the job.

However, I have a very hard time to come up with an approach at all. I tried several ideas without any success.

Comment: Can you post your attempt?

Comment: Hi, I tried a loop with some if statements, but everything more or less lead to a stackoverflow. Never really had to code a recursive function with a reference (I guess this must be the approach). Having a hard time with this one.

Comment: How is calculated the score AKA `result`

Comment: The results are coming from a separate function (I shortened it for simplicity). In the given example to calculate the score of an entry, the respective children would be multiplied by their weights and results, for the given example that would be 50% * 5 + 50% * 5.

Comment: Kind of found a solution that works as expected. If you have further ideas, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial example slightly adjusted (cast arrays to objects), it turns out, that it's then quite straightforward.

I maybe had too much respect because we are dealing with recursion.

```php
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!

$array = [
    (object) [
        'result' => null, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => [
            (object) [
                'result' => null, 
                'weight' => 50, 
                'children' => [
                    (object) [
                        'result' => 5,
                        'weight' => 75,
                        'children' => []
                     ],
                    (object) [
                        'result' => 4,
                        'weight' => 25,
                        'children' => []
                     ]
                 ]
            ],
            (object) [
                'result' => 5, 
                'weight' => 50, 
                'children' => []
            ]
        ]
    ],
    (object) [
        'result' => 3, 
        'weight' => 50, 
        'children' => []
    ],
];


function calculateScores($array, $last = null)
{
    foreach ($array as $a) {
        if (count($a->children) > 0) {
            $result = calculateScores($a->children, $a);
            if ($result) {
                $a->result = $result;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!is_null($last)) {
        $result = 0;
        foreach ($array as $a) {
            $result += $a->result * ($a->weight / 100);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

calculateScores($array);

var_dump($array);

//var_dump($last);
//var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Is that a good solution for you? Because if it work why not.

Comment: Well, not sure if it is good, :-) it at least does what I want. I kind of messed the whole thing up when looking at pure arrays because then passing/assigning by reference becomes a huge problem. I use the function within a base class that has several functions to calculate the respective results. So, I first calculate all the results for items without children and for children, and now I can just run that function to get all results. Slightly refactored (not perfect, but better than before I believe).